# How to remove controls in WinAPI (opposite of CreateWindowEX)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2015

So I can create controls I need using `CreateWindowEx`, but now I am trying to remove them completely.

I tried using

```
DestroyWindow(hwndCustom);
DestroyWindow(hwndLabel);
DestroyWindow(hwndUpDnEdtBdy);
DestroyWindow(hwndUpDnCtl);
DestroyWindow(hwndSlider);
```

And etc. but the controls are still showing in the window.

How can I remove them completely?

Do I need to repaint the window?

Controls are subclassed, the subclass is created on the click of one button and deleted on the click of another button in the main MsgProc

The `DestroyWindow` functions are in the destructor of the subclass

Creation of controls goes without issues, but they don't get removed from the window

Thanks,

-D

Comment: yes, repaint parent window

Comment: using RedrawWindow() or UpdateWindow()

Comment: I be use `InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, TRUE);`

Comment: I tried `InvalidateRect(m_hwnd, NULL, TRUE);   UpdateWindow(m_hwnd);` after `DestroyWindow` but it doesn't do anything, do I need to stick in in a specific place? I'm trying to remove on a button click in `MsgProc` Does it have to be in WM_DESTROY or something?

Comment: Is this a child window of the window which uses your MsgProc?

Comment: As always, an example that demonstrates the problem experienced will receive a better response than one posed by someone that couldn't be bothered.

Comment: `DestroyWindow()` is the correct solution. Just make sure to call it in the same thread that created the window being destroyed, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: If you do everything "by the book", there is no need for `InvalidateRect` or `UpdateWindow`. The part of the parent window that was obscured by the child will be automatically invalidated. Most likely you have a bug in the drawing code of the parent window or you are doing a lengthy operation directly in the button handler without processing messages. If so, do that lengthy operation in a separate thread so the main thread will be free to process messages.

Comment: `hwndCustom` is a  `WS_CHILD`  it's a subclassed group of controls. I'm calling `DestroyWindow(hwndCustom)` and others in the destructor of the class. Which should be in the same thread as the constructor. They are both called by the main `MsgProc` but by different buttons

Comment: Why not just hide the windows, e.g. `ShowWindow(hwndCustom, SW_HIDE);`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, the controls are being deleted, but the window still leaves them painted on. I am still having this issue and other artifacts appearing when dragging or resizing the window.

EDIT:

The problem was creating the window, I changed:

```
w_cex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
```

To

```
w_cex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
```

And it worked fine afterwards

Comment: Impossible to know this from the question. This answer appears out of thin air. Without a [mcve] there's no question, no way to answer.